# Android super slow openGL es 2.0 support on some devices on 2D game

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, sdl-2

I'm making a 2D game and to take advantage of NPOT textures I'd like to force es 2.0, but some devices get super low framerates, sub 20 on static menus. In the 10s in gameplay. We were having this problem with more devices but when we started compiling for armv7 only 2 are still acting up and I can't figure out why.

- Motorola DROID2 (Android 2.3.4 Phone)
- Samsung GT-P5113 (Android 4.2.2
  Tablet)

They run full speed 60 when I force it to use opengl es 1.0 Could I be setting something up wrong? I've tried using super simple shaders that just pass along the vertices and push out a solid color and it's still super bad.

Vertex Code:

```
#define defp highp
attribute defp vec4 Position; 
attribute defp vec4 SourceColor; 
uniform defp mat4 Transform;
attribute defp vec2 aTextureCoord;

varying defp vec4 DestinationColor; 
varying defp vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) { 
    DestinationColor = SourceColor; 
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord; 
    gl_Position = Transform * Position; 
        }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#define defp highp
varying defp vec4 DestinationColor; 
varying defp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

 void ColorMod(inout defp vec4 a, defp vec4 b)
 {
 a.x = a.x - (1.0-b.x);
 a.y = a.y - (1.0-b.y);
 a.z = a.z - (1.0-b.z);
 a.w = a.w - (1.0-b.w);
 }
void main(void) {
if(vTextureCoord.s < -99.0) 
gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
else
gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, vTextureCoord) * DestinationColor;
}
```

My 1.0 code uses the built in matrix functions, my 2.0 code manages the matrices in C++ code and binds that in as a uniform. The projection and transformation matrices are multiplied together in C++ only when they have changed(which doesn't happen often, most complicated scene has 5 different matrices).

Here is my code that draws most objects:

```
void gxDrawQuadTexture(gxSprite* sprite, const Quad& dest, const Quad& source, Color color)
{
static gxSpriteVertex v[4];
if(shadersEnabled)
{
    if(completeMatrixOutOfDate)
    {
        completeMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(_transformSlot, 1, false, completeMatrix.m);
        completeMatrixOutOfDate = false;
    }


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite->tex);
    boundSprite = sprite;



    GLenum terror = glGetError();

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);



    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        v[i].x = dest.v[i].x * _ratioX;
        v[i].y = dest.v[i].y * _ratioY;
        v[i].z = dest.v[i].z;

        v[i].color = color;

        v[i].u = (source.v[i].x ) / sprite->width;
        v[i].v = (source.v[i].y ) / sprite->height;
    }


    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
        sizeof(gxSpriteVertex), &v[0].x);
    glLogError("Position Slot");
    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, 
        sizeof(gxSpriteVertex),
        &v[0].color);
    glLogError("Color Slot");
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
        sizeof(gxSpriteVertex),
        &v[0].u);
    glLogError("Texture Coordinate Slot");
}
else
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sprite->tex);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        v[i].x = dest.v[i].x * _ratioX;
        v[i].y = dest.v[i].y * _ratioY;
        v[i].z = dest.v[i].z;
        v[i].color = color;
        v[i].u = (source.v[i].x * (sprite->unscaledWidth / float(sprite->texWidth))) / sprite->width;
        v[i].v = (source.v[i].y * (sprite->unscaledHeight / float(sprite->texHeight))) / sprite->height;
    }

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(gxSpriteVertex), &v[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(gxSpriteVertex), &v[0].u);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(gxSpriteVertex), &v[0].color);
    glLogError("Binding Arrays");
}
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glLogError("DrawArray Quad Textured");
}
```

Comment: One comment - you do not need all floats to be highp. Other than perhaps the vertices, have you tried changing the rest to mediump ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with lowp and mediump and saw no improvement in framerate.

Comment: Could it be that the OpenGLES2.0 is alone software emulated, but OpenGLES1.1 is HW accelerated ?

Comment: I don't see anything mentioning that as a possibility or anyway to detect that.